# EML, CDS - Composition/Join: Get column B~2 of table B where max( column B~1) - Possible?

Tags: max, associations, abap, cds, highest

First of all, sorry, I have no code to present, and my cds-screenshots do really just compose a header table, an items table and a statustrace table.

Our freestyle UI5 application consumes a projection, which is a composition of the underlying 3 tables, mentioned above, with redirected to bla, proper navigation properties, and so on.

The table on the ui shows mostly all fields of the orderhead table and the id and textfield of the statustable ( until now, I passed dummy-values to both ) ...

The statustable ( linked to the header table by the foreign key ordernr ) and a second key ( increm_nr, NUMC3 ) is a tracetable, which traces the status during changes, adding a record everytime, a new status is set for the order, thus incrementing the second key increm_nr ).

Therefore on the ui, in this status field, I want  to see the status of the joined/associated record of the highest increm_nr of the related order.

I hope, this is somewhat clear, if You like, I will post screenshots, BUT with a lot of blurred lines...